# Matplotlib Latex formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm trying to do some basic Latex formatting on the X axis, something that should be pretty straight forward. I have the following:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'X/Y ($\frac{XY}{kJ/$m^2$}$)')
```

Which results in the following error:

```
pyparsing.ParseFatalException: Expected \frac{num}{den} (at char 5)
```

The problem results from adding the `$m^2$` to the `\frac`. If I remove it to:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'X/Y ($\frac{XY}{kJ/m}$)')
```

The text displays with no python errors but the / does not appear in the X axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to include the extra `$`s around `$m^2$`, you are already in math mode. Try this:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'X/Y ($\frac{XY}{kJ/m^2}$)')
```

Comment: Interesting. I'd always included it in the past and it worked with some other Latex commands. Good to know I don't need it going forward. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe for clarification: With the second `$`, you actually end math mode, so everything between the second and the third `$` is interpreted in text mode. If the stuff in between works as a text (for example, if it's just an alphanumeric symbol), Latex will not throw an error. If it doesn't, it will complain, like in this case, where the `^` was not allowed in text mode.